# how to check 1 to many relations in sql

Tags: sql

From a banking domain, I have got a client and many accounts linked to it.

```
Client 1 - Account A
Client 1 - Account B
Client 2 - Account A
Client 2 - Account B
Client 2 - Account C
```

In the accounts table, there is a status flag which I want to check if set to 'Y' for all accounts of 1 client.

So we pass the test when ALL accounts for ONE client have that flag set to 'Y'. 
Does anyone know how to check it in SQL?

I have tried group by with the following shell, but doesnt seem to work:

```
select client_number
from client_table A, account table B
where B.flag = 'Y'
group by client number having count(*) =1
```

Comment: remove your count(*) = 1, because of in your case, one client have multiple accounts

Comment: not sure how it actually works for you. I do not see how you joined your `client_table` and `account_table`

Comment: Give your database description.

Comment: @cha the OP says it doesn't work ;-)

Comment: I hope my comments are taken as friendly encouragement to keep trying. A good brain teaser is often a good way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

use `count()>1` and make relationship between these two tables. i assume that you have relationship between these 2 tables using client_number

```
select A.client_number
from client_table A, account table B
where  A.client_number=B.client_number
group by B.client_number having count(*) >1
```

Comment: This ignores any rows where the status is not 'Y', so how will you know if any of them were 'N'?

Comment: @WarrenT edited my answer by removing `B.flag = 'Y'`. then it will get all the available records.

Comment: But how do you know if all of them are 'Y' or any not-Y?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select client_number
from client_table A, account table B
where B.flag = 'Y' AND B.flag != 'N'
group by client number having count(*) > 0
```

Comment: This ignores any rows where the status is not 'Y', so how will you know if any of them were 'N'?

Comment: @WarrenT: Thank you! then count condition will become greater than 0 instead of greater than 1. because of if there is only account of any client that should't be skipped.

Comment: You need to know there is at least 1 'Y' and zero that are not 'Y'.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select A.client_number 
from client_table A join account_table B on A.client_number=B.Client_number
where B.flag = 'Y'
group by A.client_number 
having count(*) >1
```

Comment: This ignores any rows where the status is not 'Y', so how will you know if any of them were 'N'?

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming column `id` in `account_table`
- Assuming column `id_account` in `client_table` for foreign key to `id` in `account_table`

Here is an ANSI 1992 version of what I believe is what you want:

```
SELECT 
    a.client_number, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id_account)) AS distinct_accounts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(ISNULL(b.id), 0, 1))) AS distinct_flagged_accounts
FROM 
    client_table a
        LEFT JOIN account_table b ON a.id_account = b.id AND b.flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY a.client_number 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id_account)) = COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(ISNULL(b.id), 0, 1)))
;
```

**FIDDLE:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aed84/1

Comment: A client has 1 record in the client table, and 5 accounts with 'Y' flag, and 2 accounts with 'N' flag, then your join will return 5 rows for the 'Y' accounts.  Therefore you will not count any accounts with  non-Y flags.

Comment: @WarrenT, no, this is a left join. Please see sql fiddle.

Comment: OK. It hadn't occurred to me that your data model would have multiple client rows per client, each with a key to a different account.  One might imagine that a bank's "client" table would have one row per client, with information about that client, possibly name, contact info, tax id, and such. Since multiple accounts can belong to one client, one would typically put a client key in the account, rather than vice versa.  So, yes this is a valid solution, but chances are that it does not apply to the user's database, unless you understood something in the question that I missed.

Comment: @WarrenT hmm according to his first table (`Client 1 - Account A`) extract I assumed he had this design, which is a wrong design obviously, but, that's his. Now I'm thinking that it is probably not the situation. We need further details of his implementation.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I see now how it could be interpreted that way. I had merely thought it was a simple way to list the logical relationships. We do need more details, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your accounts table contains the client number, so this would be used to join the tables.  But if all you want is the client numbers meeting this criteria, then it sounds like you only need to check that one table, unless there are other fields you need in your results that you did not mention.

The HAVING clause will check results after the grouping operation.  We want a group where all accounts for the client have the same value, as indicated by `count(distinct status)=1`, and where and the highest status value (in this case, all status values) for the client is 'Y'.

```
select client_number
  from account_table
  group by client_number
  having count(distinct status) = 1
     and max(status) = 'Y'
```

However, if they are joined by an ID field, then perhaps you need to use both tables in order to get the client number from the client table.

```
select client_number
  from client_table
  where client_id in (select client_id
                        from account_table
                        group by client_id
                        having count(distinct status) = 1
                           and max(status) = 'Y'
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the data I think you are looking for, you need to write two `SELECT` statements. I've made some assumptions on how your table structure might look, so you might need to adjust some column names that I use.

This first `SELECT` sets you up with the actual information you want to compare. It gives you all of your clients (by their number), the total number of accounts they have, and the `CASE` statement helps you determine the number of accounts that have a status of 'Y'.

```
SELECT client_number, COUNT(*) NumOfAccts, SUM(
    CASE WHEN A.Status = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumOfY
FROM Accounts A
GROUP BY client_number;
```

This is probably sufficient enough to determine who passes and who fails. But if you need a client name and an actual pass/fail text, we'll use this `SELECT` statement as a sub-select that gets joined back to your client table.

```
SELECT client_name, CASE WHEN NumOfAccts = NumOfY THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END PassTest
FROM Clients c INNER JOIN
(
SELECT client_number, COUNT(*) NumOfAccts, SUM(
    CASE WHEN A.Status = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NumOfY
FROM Accounts A
GROUP BY client_number
) s ON c.client_number = s.client_number;
```

As you can see, we're joining back to the client table only to get their names. We then have another `CASE` statement to compare the number of accounts with the number of accounts with a yes status. If they're equal, we'll output 'Pass'. Otherwise, we output 'Fail'.

And that should do it.